# Como capturar um elemento jquery e deixar alterado numa variável nova sem alterar na view?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Por exemplo, eu quero pegar o elemento DOM, e depois mudar, sem ele mudar o comportamento na view:

```
//aqui pego o conteúdo da html
var content = $('.content').get(0);
//aqui eu reescrevo, porém ocorre que o $('.content') também está sendo alterado...???
 var new_content = $(content).removeClass('ql-align-justify');
```

Eu quero que somente na variável ele seja modificado.

Comment: Queres criar um clone, será isso? `var content = $('.content').clone().get()`

Comment: Se eu clonar, o elemento não será duplicado na view?

Comment: Isso não é possível realizar. Você precisa clonar o objeto, conforme o @Sergio comentou ou criar um elemento "escondido" e alterar ele.

Comment: @IvanFerrer não, fica na variável até adicionares ao DOM/View. É isso que queres?

Comment: Funcionou aqui Sergio, obrigado.

Comment: @IvanFerrer ótimo! Deixei uma resposta para se outros procurarem também o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes criar um clone, que gera um elemento idêntico mas somente contido na variável. Podes então alterá-lo e depois colocar no DOM / View quando necessário.

```
var content = $('.content').clone().get();
$(content).removeClass('ql-align-justify');
// e mais tarde 
$(body).append(content);
```